# PhpStorm "Reformat Code" breaks line at PHP () calls using newline

Tags: php, phpstorm, formatter

Let's say I have this line of PHP code:

```
if ($this->request->getModuleName() == 'abc' && $this->request->getControllerName() == 'test' && $this->request->getActionName() == 'test') {
```

I then use PhpStorms "Reformat Code" function to reformat the code, it becomes this:

```
if ($this->request && $this->request->getModuleName(
    ) == 'abc' && $this->request->getControllerName(
    ) == 'test' && $this->request->getActionName() == 'test'
) {
```

But why does it add the new line after a ( and before a )? Shouldn't it better break at &&? Like this, which is better readable:

```
if ($this->request && $this->request->getModuleName() == 'abc'
    && $this->request->getControllerName() == 'test' 
    && $this->request->getActionName() == 'test'
) {
```

I cannot find the option in PhpStorms settings to fix this. The max line length is set to 120 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Check you're phpstorm code style settings. This should be helpful

- [/phpstorm/help/configuring-code-style](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-code-style.html)
- [/phpstorm/help/reformatting-source-code](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/reformatting-source-code.html)
- [/phpstorm/help/code-style](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/code-style.html)

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an option to change the code style to be like I'd expect it to be. There's the "wrapping" function for "functions" which allows to wrap after ( and before ) but it doesn't seem to be able to break at &&.